# How may I copy files from Linux to a Windows machine that is in a domain and requires authentication?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, authentication

I need a command-line method of copying files from a Linux box to a Windows machine that is in a domain and requires authentication.  I cannot install additional software or services on the Windows XP machine.  I can install any software on the Linux machine.  I've tried scp, but the connection failed and if my understanding is correct it is because scp requires that the target (windows machine) be running an ssh service.  Is there a command-line linux utility that can pass Windows domain user and password and then copy a file from the linux machine to a share on the windows machine?

Comment: so, IS there a share on the windows machine which can be accessed via name and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the normal way to achieve this is to

- mount the windows share via [smbmount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smbmount)
- just copy the files onto the mounted filesystem

you can find a lot on this topic over [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba#Client%20Access%20-%20Browsing%20SMB%20shares.)